# Windows Server 2016 Remote Access and other Roles

Tags: active-directory, vpn, windows-server-2012, remote-access, windows-server-2016

This question actually is 2 questions. I am in the middle of setting up my company's server and network. I have a host running Hyper V. I only have a standard license of Windows Server 2016 so that only allows me 2 VMs(can't purchase more). The plan is to have a DC(AD,DHCP,DNS), File Server, VPN, print server, mysql database server(won't be for another year for the database). Here are my questions:

1. I'm wondering what your recommendations are on what roles to install on each windows server. The MySQL will end up being on a Linux VM so I don't have to worry about that. But in other words, should I put the DC and Remote Access role on 1 server with the File/Printer Server on the other VM? Or should the File Server be on the DC vm? Or maybe the File Server and Remote Access on one with the DC by itself?
2. I'm still new to active directory and wondering how to setup my VPN situation. The 3 owners at my company have laptops that they use as their main machine for work and when they want to work at home. They come to work every day. How would you set this up on their machines?(they are their own personal machines as well). Do I setup the domain account on their laptops? Or do they just use their local accounts and are always using the VPN connection with they are away or at work?

I appreciate any advice or extra tips that you may have that I haven't mentioned about setting up a server(I'm suppose to be a software developer for the company, but have to wear the IT hat as well).

If there is any info that I haven't provided, let me know! Thanks!

Comment: Honestly?  This isn't even appropriate for a single question - these are two different questions.  Aside from that why even have AD?  A software developer should be developing software - not managing a Domain and server infrastructure.  Was a hosted identity solution even considered?  JumpCloud, Azure AD, etc...

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a word with management about hiring an actual sysadmin so that you can do your actual job, which is software development. Other than that, I would +1 Semicolons suggestion about Azure AD.

Comment: Also, regarding VPN, Meraki MX VPN is pretty good.

Comment: I agree with both of you but that is what is required of me and they are given me plenty of time to learn this sys admin stuff. Yea we looked at Azure and it wasn't in the budget to pay that much. Reason for AD is for security and management. There are over 30 employees(30 computers). Not fun to manage for 1 guy w/out AD. Right now they use a Windows Home as a file server and you probably could guess how many problems they run into everyday with that lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a physical Windows server, and you can also run two Windows VMs (and unlimited number of Linux VMs).
What would you run on the host v. the guests? Just think of scenario where VM adds value. The database is definitely a candidate; file/print - not so much ( you can have snapshots &c without using VM).
As for the remote access, I used VPN features of Internet router; many allow AD integration trough RADIUS (Internet Authentication Service in Network Policy Server role), and use AD credentials for VPN. Do *not* make any server (at least not one doing remote access services) visible on the Internet.
It is really a lot of things to consider - ask pointed questions along the way.... Good luck!

Comment: I'll look more into routers that have vpn features, didn't think about that, thanks!